# Select all js files inside src folder (glob)

Tags: node.js, glob

```
const glob = require('glob')

glob('src/**/**/**/**/**/**/**/***.js', {}, function(err, files) {})
```

istead of writing string like above `src/**/**/**/**/**/**/**/***.js`, I want to make it shorter and work similar way, but take any deep that can be inside of src folder. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Have a look at option called `matchBase` https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#basename-matching this `glob('*.js', { matchBase: true },, ...)` should match all js files

Comment: I need only all js files inside some folder ( in my case src) is it possible ?@Molda

Comment: Then try `glob('src/**/*.js', { matchBase: true }, ...)`

Comment: yes, seems like that's what I need ) Thanks @Molda